# Number of vendors available for each product, number of PurchaseOrderIDs where these top products are present

Tags: mysql, adventureworks

Written the Top 10 Products based on the number of Vendors available for each product.

Also, display the number of PurchaseOrderIDs where these top products are present.

```
select 
    top 10 pod.productid,
    count(vendorid)as no_of_vendors,
    count(poh.purchaseorderid)as no_of_purorder 
from purchasing.purchaseorderdetail pod join purchasing.purchaseorderheader poh  on
       pod.purchaseorderid=poh.purchaseorderid 
group by pod.productid order by count(vendorid) desc
```

I can't get the correct output. I used adventure works 20012.  Please suggest an answer for this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    top 10 pod.productid,
    count(DISTINCT(vendorid))as no_of_vendors,
    count(poh.purchaseorderid)as no_of_purorder 
from purchasing.purchaseorderdetail pod join purchasing.purchaseorderheader poh  on
       pod.purchaseorderid=poh.purchaseorderid 
group by pod.productid order by count(DISTINCT(vendorid)) desc, count(poh.purchaseorderid) DESC
```

Without DISTINCT, it's just counting the same thing as the number of purchase orders. I don't think it matters in this data here, but I would also point out that if an item appeared twice on the same purchase order, it would also double-count that if there was no DISTINCT used on that. I am also, by the way, assuming that because there are so many products that have just three vendors that you wanted it further ranked by the number of purchase orders for that product.